# i am using msal libarary for MS azure AD auth in angular 16 application, when i am clciking on the login button getting the error

Tags: angular, azure, angular-forms, msal-angular, msal

An error occurred: Error: Uncaught (in promise): BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.  For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.

//SSO login button LoginSSO(){

```
this._msalService.instance.loginPopup({ scopes: ["User.Read"]

}); }
```

// Function to initialize MSAL export

```
function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication { return new PublicClientApplication({ auth: { clientId: 'd3126f21-d2da-4b33-93a1-d0ac5caa9785', // Replace with your Azure AD application's Client ID authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/cbaf2168-de14-4c72-9d88-f5f05366dbef', redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200', // Replace with your redirect URI },

}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the below code and used msal libarary for MS Azure AD auth in Angular, and I was able to login and logout when I clicked on the login and logout buttons.***

You can check my [GitHub](https://github.com/DasariKamali/KamAngularMSAL)  repo for complete code.

**Code** :

***src/app/module.ts*** :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MsalModule, MsalService, MSAL_INSTANCE } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { IPublicClientApplication, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client_ID>', 
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_ID>', 
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200' 
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
  });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    MsalService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***src/app/auth.service.ts*** :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PublicClientApplication, AuthError } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './auth-config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private app: PublicClientApplication;
  private isMsalInitialized: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.app = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    this.initializeMsal();
  }

  private async initializeMsal(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.app.initialize();
      await this.app.handleRedirectPromise();
      this.isMsalInitialized = true; 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('MSAL initialization error:', error);
    }
  }

  async login(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.isMsalInitialized) {
      await this.initializeMsal();
    }

    try {
      const loginResponse = await this.app.loginPopup({
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read'],
      });
      console.log('Login successful', loginResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AuthError) {
        console.error('Authentication error:', error.errorMessage);
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error during login:', error);
      }
    }
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.app.logout();
  }
}
```

***src/app/sso/sso.component.html*** :

```js
<h1>Single Sign-On with Microsoft Azure AD</h1>
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
<button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully as below:

[image]

I got below in the browser with the output **URL**,

[image]

Then, I clicked on the **Login** button to sign in, got the sign-in page, and clicked on **Accept** as below.

[image]

Next, I click on the **Logout** button, and it shows my account to logout as below:

[image]