# Content security policy (CSP) error while doing SSO with Azure AD via MSAL in angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal

I am developing SSO functionality with Azure AD via MSAL in angular application. I am getting this error.

```
polyfills.9c9523e6b18dcf83.js:1 Refused to connect to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' wss:".
polyfills.9c9523e6b18dcf83.js:1 Refused to connect to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

**Content Security Meta Tag** in index.html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'self';
    connect-src 'self' https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token;
    font-src 'self';
    frame-src 'self';
    img-src 'self';
    manifest-src 'self';
    media-src 'self';
    worker-src 'none';">
```

Comment: Check my answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107575/i-am-using-msal-libarary-for-ms-azure-ad-auth-in-angular-16-application-when-i/77140322#77140322) for **sso** login with Azure AD via MSAL.

Comment: When I add this url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token, I face the same error code as yours. 
When I change it to this URL https://login.microsoftonline.com, the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Refer my SO thread answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107575/i-am-using-msal-libarary-for-ms-azure-ad-auth-in-angular-16-application-when-i/77140322#77140322).

When I add the below **URL**, I face the same error code as yours.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

When I change it to below **URL**, the error is resolved.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com;

***index.html*** :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Your Angular App</title>
<base href="/">
 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'self';
    connect-src 'self' https://login.microsoftonline.com;
    font-src 'self';
    frame-src 'self';
    img-src 'self';
    manifest-src 'self';
    media-src 'self';
    worker-src 'none';">
 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully as below,

[image]

I was able to Sign in as below.

[image]